# How to print Spring MVC model values in a JSP Page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a jsp file that receives data from a Spring MVC Controller

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page session="false"%> 

<form:form action="" commandName="someDetail">
<form:input path="name" class="form-control" />
<form:input path="address" class="form-control" />
```

This successfully displays the data inside a textbox. I want to display the data as an ordinary text without the textbox. I have tried printing it as

```
${address}
```

but it does not work. How do I print the values without the textbox?

Comment: show controller function here !

Comment: it should be like `${modelAttribute.objectAttribute}` so like 
`${someDetail.address}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is a `commandName="someDetail"`, I assume there is an object called `someDetail` in the model.

If so, you just have to write `${someDetail.address}` to print the address in the generated html.